# Pl/Sql Script for update more than 1 000 000 rows

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsql-package

I have a table:

```
id| name | organisation_name|flag  |priority|salary
1 | Mark | organisation 1   |null  |1       |100.00
2 | Inna | organisation 1   |null  |2       |400.00
3 | Marry| organisation 1   |null  |3       |500.00
4 | null | organisation 1   |250.00|null    |null
5 | Grey | organisation 2   |null  |1       |600.00
6 | Holly| organisation 2   |null  |2       |400.00
8 | null | organisation 2   |150.00|null
```

The procedure should deduct the flag from the salary of a particular organization by priority. The result for this above is below.
Result:

```
id| name | organisation_name|flag  |priority|salary
1 | Mark | organisation 1   |null  |1       |0.00
2 | Inna | organisation 1   |null  |2       |250.00
3 | Marry| organisation 1   |null  |3       |500.00
4 | null | organisation 1   |250.00|null    |null
5 | Grey | organisation 2   |null  |1       |450.00
6 | Holly| organisation 2   |null  |2       |400.00
8 | null | organisation 2   |150.00|null
```

I created Pl/sql block for this, but is so slow on one million records.
What is the fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No need for PL/SQL here. SQL has sufficient capabilities to do this and should be fast enough:

```
MERGE INTO orgs o
USING (SELECT o.id,
              greatest(o.salary - greatest(0, f.flag - nvl(sum(o.salary) over (partition by o.organisation_name order by o.priority rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0)), 0) as salary
         FROM orgs o
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT organisation_name, flag FROM orgs WHERE flag IS NOT NULL) f
                ON (f.organisation_name = o.organisation_name)
        WHERE o.priority IS NOT NULL) f
   ON (f.id = o.id)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET o.salary = f.salary;
```

For clarification: the query in USING clause is obtaining updated salaries by using window function to calculate moving total within the organisation name. Then we merge it into original table.

Answer (score 0):

To speed it up try using BULK COLLECT and FORALL options in your PL/SQL code, or as mentioned above, do it in SQL.